# How to show a popup like the validation popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At form validation when a required field is not filled then the HTML5 popup is shown :

[image]

I want to show a similar popup when a **login** already exists inside database. How to show the popup relatively to the **login** field ?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I have no clue about how to create and show this popup , and also set its text.

Comment: That is client side HTML5 validation popup. You will probably need server side validation to check duplicate values in database..

Comment: Yes I have a script checking the value in database. Then when the data already exists I want to show the popup.

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
}

.hint{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">Login exists</div>
</div>
```

Besides, you'd have to check if the login exists using AJAX.

Comment: please create a JSFiddle for it, as it will help OP.

Comment: something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/x6muZ/ sure you have to add more css to make it look more like it.

Comment: So it's very hard to recreate the system popup with that approach lol

Comment: All those popups are browser-specific, I think with this approach you'd at least get the same view.

Answer (score -1):

let your form

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="one" required />   
       <input type="submit" id="sub"></input>
   </form>
```

and jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   
  $('#sub').on('click',function(){  
      var getName=$('#one').val();
      //let's assume after checking name, it already exist then go in if condition
      if(true){
      $('#one').val('');
       $('#one').attr('data-errormessage-value-missing','already exist'); 
  }
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/njSbH/425/)

Comment: @pheromix: i hope so.

Comment: this is attr of input 
see
<input type="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please input something">

Comment: I use dreamweaver 8 so my list doesnt contain that

Comment: don't worry about your IDE. write this code. and run in browser. you can see the effect.

Comment: So I must change my submit button to an ordinary button ? Because the type of the button is "submit" actually.

Comment: It does not work when I omit the `required` attribute !

Comment: @pheromix ; yes . it won't work . and this is good to have req attribute.
for Downvoter : care to comment